# File path in jsp

Tags: file, jsp, path

Im new to Java and JSP. Pls help me in resolving this problem.

I have two files Page1.jsp and Page2.jsp under WebContent/web/jsp directory. When I click a hyperlink (using a href tag) in Page1.jsp, it should navigate to Page2.jsp.

Here is the code below written in Page1.jsp:

```
Navigate to Page2 <a href="../jsp/Page2.jsp">here</a>
```

I used below path also:

```
Navigate to Page2 <a href="../web/jsp/Page2.jsp">here</a>
```

Both the times, I am getting the error `"The requested resource (/Sample/web/jsp/Page2.jsp) is not available".`

'Sample' is my project  name specified in web.xml. And I am using Tomcat 6.0 server.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include folder name if both these .jsp files are lies in the same folder.

e.g.

Navigate to Page2 `<a href="Page2.jsp">here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to Page2.jsp can be done like this .

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/web/jsp/Page2.jsp">here</a>
```